# Spring/ maven multi module project: NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have a maven multi module project with Spring. I have a ***Core project*** that has all the data access beans along with entityManagerFactoryBean.

Now I have another maven module project that imports the context xml from the ***Core project's*** context xml file. I'm trying to override the entityManagerFactory bean by specifying this in the ***API Project***:

```
 <beans:bean parent="entityManagerFactory">
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan">
        <beans:array>
            <beans:value>com.blah.data.domains</beans:value>
            <beans:value>com.blah.api.domains</beans:value>
        </beans:array>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

This bean configuration is within the ***Core project***:

```
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="entityManager"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.blah.data.domains" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <!-- put any ORM specific stuff here -->
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

As you can see in the API project, all I'm adding `com.blah.api.domains` to the `packagesToScan` attribute. Problem is that I'm getting this issue:

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: entityManagerFactory,entityManagerFactory$child#0
```

Comment: The API project configuration is already scanning com.blah.data.domains.

You Core project is doing the same again  <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.blah.data.domains" />

The error is telling the a child property of entityManagerFactory is also defined as entityManagerFactory. I don't see this in the entry above. But can you try removing the duplicate entry to see if that fixes it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to override the entityManagerFactory in your API Module just put a wildcard in your Core Module to scan packages.

```
 <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="entityManager"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.blah.*.domains" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <!-- put any ORM specific stuff here -->
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

With a `com.blah.*.domains` all domains will be scanned and loaded.